# How to solve Error: This attribute must be localized. (at 'text' with value 'TOP_LEFT')

Tags: android

I am compiling android source using following Android.mk file :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libarity

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := TouchPanelTest

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
##################################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)


# Use the folloing include to make our test apk.
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

but it will give error :

> main.xml:19: error: Error: This attribute must be localized. (at 'text' with value 'TOP_LEFT').

mail.xml is as follows :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_left"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TOP_LEFT" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_right"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TOP_RIGHT" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_left"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BOTTOM_LEFT" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use

```
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests
```

in the Android.mk to omits the localization check.

Another way is to disable localization check in build system. Comment the line 81 in  `build/core/package.mk`

```
#LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := $(LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS) -z
```

Comment: What does **package.mk** look like?

Answer (score 9):

Best practice for Android apps is to define all of the non-dynamic content in resource files. This lets you define different resource files for different languages, for example. Normally, this is just a recommendation and the Android SDK doesn't complain if you hard-code values in your layout xml. The Android *source* build system, however, requires that all strings be defined in a "values" resource. This is probably intended to protect system builders from accidentally leaving content in a system image that won't display in the user's chosen language.

What you need to do is move those string values out of the layout and define them in `res/values/` instead. The usual place for string values is in `res/values/strings.xml`, but the actual file can be named anything you like as long as it's in that directory.

For example, in res/values/string.xml:

```
<string name="topLeftContent">TOP_LEFT</string>
```

And in your `main.xml` layout, refer to the content by name:

```
    android:text="@string/topLeftContent"
```

For more details on the how and why of this, see Google's documentation on [Localization in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Comment: Yes, this is a very subtle error to catch.  Without gradle, we will be dealing with these errors.